# SQLAlchemy is there a way to Returning result after Delete execution

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I can't find equivalent solution about Returning clause

```
DELETE FROM items
WHERE sub_item_id IN %(sub_item_ids)s
RETURNING item_id, sub_item_id,
```

I did this in SQLAlchemy :

```
purge_family = session.query(ItemItem).filter(ItemItem.sub_item_id.in_(sub_item_ids))

.delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

I need to return item_id, sub_item_id set upon execution of DELETE statement.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need that?

Comment: because i need to know (PosgreSql) , how many items are deleted. for example i have list of 10 items, after it ll only delete 4 items. then i continue to run other treatment

Comment: But [Query.delete()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) already returns the count of matched rows.

Comment: yepp the count don't the values what i need to return

Comment: I still have my doubts that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Supposedly the "other treatment" depends on the ids of the removed rows somehow?

Comment: Yes, i want to get the ids removed, to make other treatment in other table

Comment: thanks, finally i suppose there are two solution  : execute query as is use Core constructs (Answer) OR Excute query  with                                                              query = session.execute(sql_delete, params_s);                                                               result = query.fetchall()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To execute your query as is use Core constructs:

```
stmt = ItemItem.__table__.delete().\
    where(ItemItem.sub_item_id.in_(sub_item_ids)).\
    returning(ItemItem.item_id, ItemItem.sub_item_ids)

results = session.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```